# Fullcalendar event property acceptance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I am working on a calendar where I would like to display a bit more information about my events.
Below I show you the list of events I'm using:

```
export default [
  {
    id: 13,
    title: 'Sport Event',
    start: new Date(2019, 5, 20, 19, 30, 0),
    end: new Date(2019, 5, 20, 22, 0, 0),
    recurrence: "weekly"
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    title: 'Flight to France',
    start: new Date(2019, 5, 17, 13, 30, 0),
    end: new Date(2019, 5, 17, 15, 0, 0),
    recurrence: "once"
  },{
    id: 16,
    title: 'Party',
    start: new Date(2019, 5, 17, 15, 0, 0),
    end: new Date(2019, 5, 17, 17, 0, 0),
    matchRef: 'match/122123123332',
    recurrence: "once"
  },{
    id: 15,
    title: 'Birthday',
    start: new Date(2019, 5, 17, 20, 30, 0),
    end: new Date(2019, 5, 18, 0, 0, 0),
    recurrence: "monthly"
  }
]
```

Since I'm already displaying the title, start and end, I would like to display the value of recurrence property in my events. I'm working with ReactJS. This seems really simple to implement, while I'm new with Fullcalendar-react, so I'm sorry in advance.

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you [start here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender).

Comment: BTW, rather than simply display a string saying "weekly", you know you could actually make your events recur for real... see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin

Comment: Thanks @ADyson! I have found the solution!